# Java stream List<X> to Map<X, List<Y>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to write a piece of code that does the following (pseudocodish), but with streams. I'm trying to figure it out, but I can't seem to get it mapped correctly. I'm probably missing some knowledge of I'm overlooking something. Anybody has the knowledge to help me out?

Thanks in advance!! :-)

```
Map<X, List<Y>> result= ...;

List<X> allX = getAllNeededX();
for(X x : allX) {
    List<Y> matchingY = getMatchingY(x.id);
    SortListOfYByProperty
    result.put(x, sortedY)
}
```

Comment: Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: What are the keys and values of your map supposed to represent?

Comment: What've you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some options.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<X, List<Y>> results = new HashMap<>();
    List<X> allX = getAllX();

    //simple way to just replace old for loop with forEach
    allX.stream().forEach(x -> {
        List<Y> matchingY = getMatchingY(x.id);
        sortListY(matchingY);
        results.put(x, matchingY);
    });

    //a little bit fancier, assumes sortListY return List<Y>
    allX.stream()
            .map((X x) -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(x, sortListY(getMatchingY(x.id))))
            .forEach(e -> results.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));

    //more fancy, assumes sortListY return List<Y>
    Map<X, List<Y>> results2 = allX.stream()
            .map((X x) -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(x, sortListY(getMatchingY(x.id))))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));

    //most fancy, assumes sortListY return List<Y>
    Map<X, List<Y>> results3 = allX.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), x -> sortListY(getMatchingY(x.id))));


    //most fancy part 2, assumes sortListY return List<Y>
    Map<X, List<Y>> results4 = allX.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> sortListY(getMatchingY(x.id))));

}
```

Comment: You should perform the `sortListY()` inside `collect()`, this would avoid the intermediate mapping to entries.

Comment: @DidierL good idea, let me try that,  thanks

Answer (score 1):

Didier's link helped me a lot.

I could make the first list of X and a seperate stream for the sorted list of Y, but I wasn't able to combine it all.

With the link of Didier I came to the following, which made my unittest succeed:

```
return getAllX().stream().collect(toMap(x -> x, x -> getSortedAndMatchingY(x.id)));
```

By moving the sorting to a separate method as the above answer suggested and using some input from the link this came to mind and it seems to work. Thanks for the input :-)